# NameError: name 'values' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models

I am getting the error "NameError: name 'values' is not defined". Below is a segment of code similar to my code. I also don't know if my implementation of the class without the **init** function is correct.

```
from django.db import models
...

class Car(models.Model, values):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand = values['brand']
    year = values['year']
    mpg = values['mpg']
```

Comment: What is values? Have you defined a class called `values` that the model can subclass? No, judging by the error.

Comment: You definitely want to define that in the `__init__(self)` method, as that is the class constructor.

Comment: Yes, it is not defined.